# FQL query to retrieve id,name of 'Pages' with specific category

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Can I query through FQL list of pages(ids & names) on facebook with category as University or other categories ?

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=page&q=university

This will return the name, id, and category of the page. You can then filter out your results to show those that have the specific word "University" in the category.

Comment: This requires the page name to have the word `category` and does not return all pages in that category. You will likely need to use FQL 2.0